# Finding Lowest, Second Lowest, and Highest Values in an Array in PowerPoint VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

When a user runs a GUI on a PPT slide it brings up a userform, pictured below.

[image]

They can select up to 3 hazards in the check boxes. I am trying to figure out how I would write the code so that the checkbox with the lowest number in its Tag goes into "Hazard1", the Tag with the second lowest number (of the up to 3 that can be selected) goes into Hazard2, and the Tag with the third lowest number goes into Hazard3. Each Tag property for any checkbox only has a single number in it. This is what I will use for my rankings priority.

Here is the code so far:

```
Private Sub Hazards()
    Call Dictionary.HazardsDict

   'References the Dictionary for the Hazard Image options.

    Dim chkboxes As Variant
    Dim iCtrl As Long

    Select Case CountSelectedCheckBoxes(chkboxes)
        Case Is > 3
            MsgBox "Too many selected checkboxes!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "please select three checkboxes only!", vbCritical
        Case Is = 1 'If only one checkbox is selected
            For iCtrl = LBound(chkboxes) To UBound(chkboxes)
              HazardList = Array(chkboxes(iCtrl).Caption)
              Debug.Print chkboxes(iCtrl).Caption
              Next
                'MsgBox chkboxes(iCtrl).Tag '<--| here you output each selected checkbox Tag. This is the "number" to use in the ranking
            For Each Ky In HazardList
                ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("Hazard1").Fill.UserPicture (dict5.Item(Ky)(0))
                ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("Hazard1Text").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = dict5.Item(Ky)(1)
            Next
        Case Is = 2 'If exactly 2 checkboxes are selected
            For iCtrl = LBound(chkboxes) To UBound(chkboxes)
              HazardList = Array(chkboxes(iCtrl).Caption)
              Debug.Print chkboxes(iCtrl).Caption
            Next
            For Each Ky In HazardList
                ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("Hazard1").Fill.UserPicture (dict5.Item(Ky)(0)) 'The checkbox with the lowest number in its Tag would go here.
                ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("Hazard1Text").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = dict5.Item(Ky)(1)
                ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("Hazard2").Fill.UserPicture (dict5.Item(Ky)(0)) 'The checkbox with the second lowest tag number would go here
                ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("Hazard2Text").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = dict5.Item(Ky)(1)
            Next
    End Select

    Set dict5 = Nothing

End Sub
```

The dictionary the above code refers to is as follows:

```
Public dict, dict2, dict3, dict4, dict5 As Object, Key, val 'Makes the dictionaries public so they can be accessed by other Modules.

Sub MainImageDict()

'This is the dictionary for the Main Image portion of the slides.

Set dict3 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Key = "Day 1 High Temperatures": val = Array("URL_to_Image")
dict3.Add Key, val
Key = "Day 2 High Temperatures": val = Array("URL_to_Image")
dict3.Add Key, val

End Sub

Function CountSelectedCheckBoxes(chkboxes As Variant) As Long
    Dim ctrl As Control
    ReDim chkboxes(1 To Me.Controls.count)

    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls '<--| loop through userform controls
        If TypeName(ctrl) = "CheckBox" Then '<--| check if current control is a "checkbox" one
            If ctrl Then '<--| check if it's "checked"
                CountSelectedCheckBoxes = CountSelectedCheckBoxes + 1 '<--| update checked checkboxes counter
                Set chkboxes(CountSelectedCheckBoxes) = ctrl '<--| store it in the array
            End If
        End If
    Next
    If CountSelectedCheckBoxes > 0 Then ReDim Preserve chkboxes(1 To CountSelectedCheckBoxes) '<--|size checkboxes array to actual checked checkboxes found
End Function
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Can you show the code for `CountSelectedCheckBoxes` so that we can get a sense of the checkbox objects?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to include that! I have updated the post.

Comment: I think you will need to upload a file - there is too much going on here for us to solve as is.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by rejiggering your `CountSelectedCheckBoxes` function return a struct containing the selected checkboxes and the count.  Below is untested code but I think it will give you an idea of how to proceed.

**Declare the custom type (struct)**

```
Public Type structChkBoxeses
    selectedCount   As Long
    first           As CheckBox
    second          As CheckBox
    third           As CheckBox
End Type
```

**Function that returns the selected checkboxes and their count**

Note that you need to fix the logic that orders the checkboxes correctly.

```
Function GetSelectedChkBoxes(structChkBoxes As structChkBoxeses) As structChkBoxeses

    Dim ctrl As Control


    ReDim chkboxes(1 To Me.Controls.Count)

    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls '<--| loop through userform controls
        If TypeName(ctrl) = "CheckBox" Then '<--| check if current control is a "checkbox" one
            If ctrl Then '<--| check if it's "checked"

                With structChkBoxes
                    .selectedCount = .selectedCount + 1 '<--| update checked checkboxes counter

                    ' you need to add some logic here but
                    ' basically you want get all the checkboxes
                    ' assigned to the right variables

                    If .third Is Nothing Then
                        Set .third = ctrl
                    Else
                        If .third.Tag > ctrl.Tag Then
                            Set .second = .third
                            Set .third = ctrl
                        End If
                    End If
                End With

            End If
        End If
    Next

    GetSelectedChkBoxes = structChkBoxes

End Function
```

**Example of how to use the struct to fetch correct dictionary item**

```
Sub Hazards(structChkBoxes As structChkBoxeses)

    For Each Ky In HazardList
        With ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange
            .Shapes("Hazard1").Fill.UserPicture (dict5.Item(structChkBoxes.first)(0))  'The checkbox with the lowest number in its Tag would go here.
            .Shapes("Hazard1Text").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = dict5.Item(Ky)(1)
            .Shapes("Hazard2").Fill.UserPicture (dict5.Item(structChkBoxes.second)(0)) 'The checkbox with the second lowest tag number would go here
            .Shapes("Hazard2Text").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = dict5.Item(Ky)(1)
        End With
    Next

End Sub
```

Possibly `structChkBoxes.first` needs to be something like `CInt(structChkBoxes.first.tag)`.  It's not entirely clear to me what you're using as the dictionary key.

You will also need to change some other code due to the fact that your function that counted the checkboxes is now returning a struct instead of an array.

Comment: Ok, awesome. I definitely see where you are going with this. I will be able to test out this method tomorrow and I'll get back to you. Thanks!